# Terraform additional security group for managed nodes in EKS

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks, aws-security-group

I am trying to add an additional security group to the existing managed nodes in EKS module: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks

if I add:

```
      vpc_security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.additional.id]
```

to: `eks_managed_node_group_defaults`
Then Terraform wants to create new launch template and remove existing SG from it.

Comment: How were those SG's attached in the first place?